# Minitest:Test in Ruby on Rails produces more assertions than I expect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, minitest

I'm starting to use **Minitest** for doingi unit test on rails.

Here is my first test case for *Product* model.

```
require "test_helper"

class ProductTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "product price must be positive" do
    product = Product.new(title: "My Book Title",
                          description: "yyy",
                          image_url: "zzz.jpg")
    product.price = -1
    assert product.invalid?, "negative price of a product must be invalid."
    assert product.errors.has_key?(:price), "an invalid product must have an error"

    product.price = 0
    assert product.invalid?, "negative price of a product must be invalid."
    assert product.errors.has_key?(:price), "an invalid product must have an error"

    product.price = 1
    assert product.valid?, "positive price of a product must be valid."
    assert_empty product.errors, "a valid product must have no error"
  end
end
```

I've added **6 assertions** for this test case. 
However, if I run this test case, the console output produces **7 assertions** run.

```
$ rake test test/models/product_test.rb 


[DEPRECATION] Ahoy subscribers are deprecated
Run options: --seed 31334

# Running:

.

Finished in 0.260717s, 3.8356 runs/s, 23.0134 assertions/s.

1 runs, 7 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Is there anyone who can help me to figure out **the reason of mismatching the number of assertions**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Here is my first test case" - is there another test case?

Comment: Could you please run your tests with `bundle exec rake test -v` and show output?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev No. This is the only test case that I have.

Comment: @Зелёный Here is the output.

`$ bundle exec rake test -v 

[DEPRECATION] Ahoy subscribers are deprecated
Run options: -v --seed 14282

# Running:

ProductTest#test_product_price_must_be_positive = 0.23 s = .

Finished in 0.235255s, 4.2507 runs/s, 29.7549 assertions/s.

1 runs, 7 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips`

Comment: If I commented out the last assertion (ie., `assert_empty`), then the console output produces only 5 assertions. So, it seems `assert_empty` produces 2 assetions but I don't know why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at [the source](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/MiniTest/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_empty), `assert_empty` indeed makes two assertions for the price of one.

```
def assert_empty obj, msg = nil
  msg = message(msg) { "Expected #{mu_pp(obj)} to be empty" }
  assert_respond_to obj, :empty?
  assert obj.empty?, msg
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :)